# gpg encrypting files with

Tags: bash, shell, whitespace, gnupg

Essentially, what I am trying to do is batch gpg encrypt files with whitespaces in the filenames and my quotes are way off.

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/sh

input_path="/opt/ftp_dirs/upload/*.*"
archive_path='/opt/archives'
encrypt_path='/opt/archives/encrypted'

for encrypted in $input_path; do
    decrypted="$encrypted`date +%Y%m%d%N`.gpg"
    echo "$encrypted"
    /usr/bin/gpg --batch --no-tty --yes --output $decrypted --recipient someone@something.com --passphrase password --encrypt $encrypted
done
exit
```

Which is fine for files with no whitespace.

Are my quotes are off? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When referencing variables, if you use quotes (for example `"$decrypted"`), the content is not interpreted by the shell and is passed literally to the command as a single parameter.

If you don't use quotes (for example, simply using `$decrypted`, like you do), the content is intepreted by the shell, which mean that spaces produce multiple parameters to the command.

Use quotes when referencing variables, so the shell doesn't interpret them and the spaces in the path are respected as you want:

```
/usr/bin/gpg --batch --no-tty --yes --output "$decrypted" --recipient someone@something.com --passphrase password --encrypt "$encrypted"
```

Comment: I swear to beans I double quoted those two things.

Thank you! This worked.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to quote `"$encrypted"` and `"$decrypted"`.

```
gpg --batch --no-tty --yes --output "$decrypted" --recipient someone@something.com --passphrase password --encrypt "$encrypted"
```